# Is $\oint_S e^xdy\,dz-ye^xdz\,dx+3z\,dx\,dy$ solvable by direct method?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> $$\oint_S e^xdy\,dz-ye^xdz\,dx+3z\,dx\,dy, \quad S:x^2+y^2\le a^2,\quad 0\le z\le h$$

I tried to solve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZlQf.png) integral by Gauss and the answer was $(3\pi a^2h)$
but it is required to verify Gauss i tried to integrate over each side but the resulting exponential function can't be integrated by usual methods. Can you please tell me how to do it by direct method. Thanks.

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Imagers can't be browsed, and aren't accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help on formatting math on this site here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I have ever seen that perfectly dreadful notation for a surface integral before. I think it stands for the flux out of the closed surface $S$
$$\unicode{x222F}_S\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A$$
of the vector field $\vec F=\langle e^x,-ye^x,3z\rangle$. Assuming that is the case, we break $S$ into $3$ parts: the top $S_1$ where $z=h$, the curvy part $S_2$ where $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r=a$, and the bottom $S_3$ where $z=0$.

On $S_2$, $\vec r=\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle a\cos\theta,a\sin\theta,z\rangle$, so the differential
$$d\vec r=\langle-a\sin\theta,a\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta+\langle0,0,1\rangle dz$$
Since the $d\theta$ term is the vector step you take along $S_2$ when $\theta$ goes from $\theta$ to $\theta+d\theta$ and the $dz$ term is the vector step you take along $S_2$ when $z$ goes from $z$ to $z+dz$, it follows that
$$d^2\vec A=\pm\langle-a\sin\theta,a\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta\times\langle0,0,1\rangle dz=\langle a\cos\theta,a\sin\theta,0\rangle d\theta\, dz$$
having the area of the parallelogram with these two vector steps as edges and normal to $S_2$, is the required vector areal element $d^2\vec A$. We took the $(+)$ sign so as to get the outward normal. Along the surface $S_2$,
$$\vec F=\langle e^{a\cos\theta},-a\sin\theta e^{a\cos\theta},3z\rangle$$
So
$$\unicode{x222F}_{S_2}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=\int_0^h\int_0^{2\pi}\left(a\cos\theta e^{a\cos\theta}-a^2\sin^2\theta e^{a\cos\theta}\right)d\theta\, dz$$
Now, it looks like we are in trouble here, but we can integrate by parts to get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}a\cos\theta e^{a\cos\theta}d\theta&=\left.a\sin\theta e^{a\cos\theta}\right|_0^{2\pi}-\int_0^{2\pi}a\sin\theta e^{a\cos\theta}\left(-a\sin\theta\right)d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}a^2\sin^2\theta e^{a\cos\theta}d\theta\end{align}$$
So
$$\unicode{x222F}_{S_2}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=\int_0^h\int_0^{2\pi}\left(a^2\sin^2\theta e^{a\cos\theta}-a^2\sin^2\theta e^{a\cos\theta}\right)d\theta\, dz=0$$
The top is easy: along $S_1$, $\vec r=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,h\rangle$,
$$d\vec r=\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle dr+\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta$$
$$d^2\vec A=\pm\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle dr\times\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta=\langle0,0,r\rangle dr\, d\theta$$
Where the (+) sign is again outward. Then along $S_1$,
$$\vec F=\langle e^{r\cos\theta},r\sin\theta e^{r\cos\theta},3h\rangle$$
so
$$\unicode{x222F}_{S_1}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=\int_0^a\int_0^{2\pi}3hrd\theta dr=(3h)(2\pi)\left(\frac12a^2\right)$$
On the bottom along $S_3$, $\vec r=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,0\rangle$,
$$d\vec r=\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle dr+\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta$$
$$d^2\vec A=\pm\langle \cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle dr\times\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle d\theta=-\langle0,0,r\rangle drd\theta$$
Where now the (-) sign is outward. Then along $S_3$,
$$\vec F=\langle e^{r\cos\theta},r\sin\theta e^{r\cos\theta},0\rangle$$
so
$$\unicode{x222F}_{S_3}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=\int_0^a\int_0^{2\pi}0\,d\theta\, dr=0$$
Adding up the results,
$$\unicode{x222F}_S\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=\unicode{x222F}_{S_1}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A+\unicode{x222F}_{S_2}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A+\unicode{x222F}_{S_3}\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A=3\pi a^2h+0+0=3\pi a^2h$$
The divergence
$$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec F=\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\rangle\cdot\langle e^x,-ye^x,3z\rangle=e^x-e^x+3=3$$
So
$$\int\int\int_V\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec Fd^3V=3V=3(\pi a^2h)$$
Because the integrand is constant within the volume $V$. Thus the divergence theorem is verified.